# PowerShell - Shorten namespace names so it's easier to access types

Tags: powershell, namespaces

Is there a method of shortening PowerShell namespace references?

Typing `[RootNameSpace1.NameSpace2.Namepsace3+SomeEnum]::SomeValue` is taxing and not a very good user expierence. I realize that you can reference `System` level objects without a namespace such that `[Type]::GetType(...` will work. Is there some manifest I could create or command I could use to shorten lengthy namespaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any methods accepting Enums will accept strings, but this is for Enums only and where there is no ambiguity (meaning there are no other overloads with a signature matching strings in this fashion.)

If you're on powershell v2.0, you can (ab)use Type Accelerators. I blogged about this before, and Joel Bennett wrapped up my technique in a handy script:

http://poshcode.org/1869

UPDATE (2020): this link is broken, but for current versions of powershell there is an easier way.

```bsh
using namespace System.Collections.Generic;
$list = new-object List # also: $list = [list]::new()
```

-Oisin

Comment: The link you provided is not accessible (anymore). Can you add the relevant part of your answer in the answer, so it is available without the external depency?

Comment: If anyone wants to see the original, its available via archive.org - https://web.archive.org/web/20161030010712/http://poshcode.org/1869

Answer (score 7):

Lengthy types can be assigned to variables and then used via those variables:

```
# enum values
$rvk = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]
$rvk::Binary
$rvk::DWord

# static members
$con = [System.Console]
$con::CursorLeft
$con::WriteLine('Hello there')

# just to be sure, look at types
.{
    $rvk::Binary
    $con::WriteLine
    $con::CursorLeft
} |
% { $_.GetType() }
```

Comment: That works for a simple solution. I was hoping there was a way to achieve it without our end user having to create these variables or without having to create them internally and then expose some sort of documentation.  

Thanks!